# Proving a Mapping Property Between Tempered Distributions and Schwartz Functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Say I have a Schwartz function $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$. Consider a map $\psi(u)(x)=\langle u,\varphi(x,\cdot)\rangle$ for $u\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n}).$ I'd like to know how to show (1) that if $\psi:\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and (2) that the map $\psi$ is continuous.

For (1), I initially wrote $$|x^\alpha D^\beta \psi (u)(x)|=|\langle x^\alpha D^\beta u,\varphi(x,\cdot)\rangle|=|\langle  u,x^\alpha D^\beta\varphi(x,\cdot)\rangle|$$ for any $x$, but I'm not sure if moving the $x^\alpha D^\beta$ over actually makes sense here.  Typically, we do this when $x$ is the variable that the action is with respect to, which is not the case here. If this were allowed, then the fact that $\varphi$ is Schwartz would guarantee that $x^\alpha D^\beta \varphi(x,\cdot)$ is Schwartz, and this would be finite for any $x$ since $u$ is tempered. So, it comes down to simply understanding *how* the $x^\alpha D^\beta$ action is defined.

For (2), I tried to use the sequential criterion, but I could not show that if $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $\mathcal{S}'$ (i.e. weak$^*$/pointwise), then $\psi (u_n)\rightarrow \psi (u)$ in $\mathcal{S}$ (i.e. in every Schwartz seminorm). I think it would come from the first part, as if I could move over the $x^\alpha D^\beta,$ then I would have $$x^\alpha D^\beta(\psi(u_n)-\psi(u))=\langle (u_n-u), x^\alpha D^\beta \varphi(x,\cdot)\rangle\rightarrow 0$$ since $x^\alpha D^\beta \varphi(x,\cdot)$ is Schwartz and $\langle u_n, f\rangle \rightarrow \langle u, f\rangle$ for any $f\in\mathcal{S}.$

Alternatively, since $\mathcal{S}$ is dense in $\mathcal{S}'$ in the weak$^*$ topology, might it suffice to check these claims for $u\in\mathcal{S}$ and extend by density? It's not clear to me how that extension process would work.

EDIT: Perhaps, I can make sense of the derivative claim by showing that difference quotients converge? Also, I believe that moving that $x^\alpha$ from one side to the other is justified since, for a fixed $x$, this is as good as a constant as far as $u$ is concerned, so I can use linearity. Is that correct?

Comment: Asking whether $\psi:\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ doesn't make much sense, because in fact $\psi:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$. Maybe what you actually had in mind was $\psi(u)(x)=\langle u,\varphi(x,\cdot)\rangle$? Or, with the notation  you used, the obvious question seems to be whether $\psi\in\mathcal S$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I meant to write $\psi (u)(x),$ my mistake!

Comment: Now I'm not, did you show that continuous on the Schwartz space implies $|<u,\phi>| \le C_u \sum_{|r|,|s| \le N_u} \|D_y^r y^s \phi\|_\infty$, the argument is quite the same as in https://mathoverflow.net/a/348398/84768

Comment: @reuns Do you mean have I seen the definition of continuity for elements of $\mathcal{S}'$ in that manner. If so, I have seen that argument before awhile ago. I think what was tripping me up on your answer was that I wasn't sure of the definition of a continuous function between two locally convex topological vector spaces in terms of seminorms. I looked it up yesterday and saw that was what your answer was showing. Looking back at that argument, I see exactly what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\varphi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n), u \in S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ let $$T[u](x) = <u,\varphi(x,.)> \ \in R, \qquad (D_x^a x^b) T[u](x_0)=<u,(D_x^a x^b \varphi)(x_0,.)>$$

Since $u$ is a tempered distribution you know that for some $N_u,C_u$, for all $\phi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ $$|<u,\phi>| \le C_u \sum_{|r|,|s| \le N_u} \|D_y^r y^s \phi\|_\infty$$
whence

$$\sup_{x_0} |(D_x^a x^b) T[u](x_0)|=\sup_{x_0}  |<u,(D_x^a x^b \varphi)(x_0,.)>|\\ \le \sup_{x_0} C_u\sum_{|r|,|s| \le N_u} \|D_y^r y^s (D_x^a x^b \varphi)(x_0,.)\|_\infty \le C_u \sum_{|r|,|s| \le N_u} \|D_y^r y^s D_x^a x^b \varphi \|_\infty = C_u \kappa(N_u,a,b)$$

Which is quite the definition of that $u \mapsto T[u]$ is a continuous linear map $S'(\mathbb{R}^n) \to S(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I haven't checked but I also think the map is not continuous if $S'$ is given its usual (wrong) topology, i.e., the weak-star one. If $S'$ has the strong topology then everything works fine. Not only $\psi$ is continuous but the map $\phi\mapsto\psi$ is a TVS isomorphism (all topologies being strong,i.e., given by uniform convergence on bounded sets).

Comment: Also, this result is just a part of Fubini's Theorem for temperate distributions. The best way to prove it is to rewrite it in terms of sequence spaces, thanks to Hermite functions.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I didn't notice, but I think you're right. The RHS of the inequality would need to be in terms of the seminorms coming from the weak* topology, I think. Also, the result should use the weak* topology on $\mathcal{S}',$ not the strong one. For reference, I was trying to fill in the details of the proof of theorem 4.1 on page 40 of https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/semiclassical.pdf

Comment: Why do you care, continuous for the strong topology implies continuous for the weak topology. @user269711

Comment: @reuns: Could you state a bit more completely the thm about strong continuity implies weak continuity. For what maps and spaces?

Comment: @user269711: I quickly looked at the lectures by Evans and Zworzki and they nowhere define what it means for a linear map $T:S'\rightarrow S$ to be continuous. The correct definition of continuity is: you put a topology on the two spaces, then you use the definition of continuity from your point set topology course. The problem is: they give you the topology of $S$ but not that of $S'$. Saying which sequences converge is insufficient. So when they say "T is continuous", I believe what they mean to say is that if $u_k\rightarrow u$ in $S'$ then $T(u_k)\rightarrow T(u)$...

Comment: ...in other words they are talking about the notion of sequential continuity which is weaker than true continuity. Also, as long as you are considering sequences (rather than nets) you will not see the difference between weak-star and strong topologies.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam and the convergence of $T(u_k)$ is in $\mathcal{S},$ I presume?

Comment: yes. The $T(u_k)$'s are in the target space which is $S$ so the convergence is with respect to the corresponding topology.